# Каркас Android приложения для игр

Tags: разработка-игр, android, архитектура, java

Конечно на просторах интернета есть туториалы, но многие из них освящают только работу с OpenGL. Может кто-то уже занимался разработкой? Как организовать life-cycle приложения для работы с графикой и звуком. Можно в общих чертах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так же, как это делается и в обычных инграх. Материалов по геймдеву полно. Ключевое слово для поисков gamedev.

Часто в играх запускается несколько потоков для обработки рисования, звука, таймлайна и выполнения основной логики игры, для отлова событий ввода-вывода. Либо, можно наоборот затолкать всё кроме звука в один и пытаться работать только в нём, но это несколько сложнее.

Небольшие примеры

http://code.google.com/p/android-gamedev/

https://github.com/deesaster/Android-Game-Template

http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development